# How do I access the selection in this kendo ui modal dropdown?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

On this page: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/index click any date to begin creating a new event in the calendar. Select "Bob" as the owner. Now how could you access that client side before the form is submitted? Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Scheduler save event(http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#events-save)
This triggers when you click the "Save" button and you have access to all the event data through e.event and the scheduler itself through e.sender.

You can even cancel the save with e.preventDefault().

Note that you do not have direct access to "Bob" through e.event...you only have access to ownerId which you then can look up in e.sender.resources to get "Bob".

Demo of save event: http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/EvaCo